# Caveats of running eject on create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I currently started a new project using create-react-app, but I'd like to add some minor custom configurations to my webpack config. (automatically address .scss files as .module.scss, etc)

As far as I learned, the only way to do that it running eject, which would allow me to configure babel\webpack myself.

I was wondering, what caveats could that have? basically, why WOULDN'T I wan't to run eject?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Does Eject do in Create React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737652/what-does-eject-do-in-create-react-app)

Comment: If you want to customise things in a way that a non ejected `create-react-app` application does not allow you to, then you don't have a choice but to eject. You wouldn't want to eject if there was no reason for you to need to eject basically since create-react-app hides a lot of the complexity you don't need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

**DO it**, and see it for yourself, create new project in another directory and experiment with it; eject make things look a little more complicated, but it's OK, its like taking a look inside the hardware of your computer.

However if your project directory is under version control, you can reverse the `eject` too